# How do you encrypt large files / byte streams in Go?

Tags: go, encryption, aes, large-data

I have some large files I would like to AES encrypt before sending over the wire or saving to disk. While it seems possible to [encrypt streams](https://golang.org/src/crypto/cipher/example_test.go#L335), there seems to be [warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39378051/making-gcm-cbc-ciphers-streamable-in-golang) against [doing this](https://www.imperialviolet.org/2014/06/27/streamingencryption.html) and instead people recommend splitting the files into chunks and using GCM or crypto/nacl/secretbox.

> Processing streams of data is more difficult due to the authenticity requirement. We can’t encrypt-then-MAC: by it’s nature, we usually don’t know the size of a stream. We can’t send the MAC after the stream is complete, as that usually is indicated by the stream being closed. We can’t decrypt a stream on the fly, because we have to see the entire ciphertext in order to check the MAC. Attempting to secure a stream adds enormous complexity to the problem, with no good answers. The solution is to break the stream into discrete chunks, and treat them as messages.

- https://leanpub.com/gocrypto/read

> Files are segmented into 4KiB blocks. Each block gets a fresh random 128 bit IV each time it is modified. A 128-bit authentication tag (GHASH) protects each block from modifications.

- https://nuetzlich.net/gocryptfs/forward_mode_crypto/

> If a large amount of data is decrypted it is not always possible to buffer all decrypted data until the authentication tag is verified. Splitting the data into small chunks fixes the problem of deferred authentication checks but introduces a new one. The chunks can be reordered... ...because every chunk is encrypted separately. Therefore the order of the chunks must be encoded somehow into the chunks itself to be able to detect rearranging any number of chunks.

- https://github.com/minio/sio

Can anyone with actual cryptography experience point me in the right direction?

## Update

I realized after asking this question that there is a difference between simply not being able to fit the whole byte stream into memory (encrypting a 10GB file) and the byte stream *also* being an unknown length that could continue long past the need for the stream's start to be decoded (an 24-hour live video stream).

I am mostly interested in large blobs where the end of the stream can be reached before the beginning needs to be decoded. In other words, **encryption that does not require the whole plaintext/ciphertext to be loaded into memory at the same time.**

Comment: are your files of well known size before you start the encryption process? or is their size calculated during the encryption window?

Comment: Both. I have files on the filesystem _I know the size of_, and streams coming from a client that I don't trust. However, I impose a maximum byte size either way.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As you've already discovered from your research, there isn't much of an elegant solution for *authenticated* encryption of large files.

There are traditionally two ways to approach this problem:

- Split the file into chunks, encrypt each chunk individually and let each chunk have its own authentication tag.  AES-GCM would be the best mode to use for this.  This method causes file size bloating proportionate to the size of the file.  You'll also need a unique nonce for each chunk.  You also need a way to indicate where chunks begin/end.
- Encrypt using AES-CTR with a buffer, call `Hash.Write` on an HMAC for each buffer of encrypted data.  The benefit of this is that encrypting can be done in one pass.  The downside is that decryption requires one pass to validate the HMAC and then another pass to actually decrypt.  The upside here is that the file size remains the same, plus roughly ~48 or so bytes for the IV and HMAC result.

Neither is ideal, but for very large files (~2GB or more), the second option is probably preferred.

I have included an example of encryption in Go using the second method below.  In this scenario, the last 48 bytes are the IV (16 bytes) and the result of the HMAC (32 bytes).  Note the HMACing of the IV also.

```
const BUFFER_SIZE int = 4096
const IV_SIZE int = 16

func encrypt(filePathIn, filePathOut string, keyAes, keyHmac []byte) error {
    inFile, err := os.Open(filePathIn)
    if err != nil { return err }
    defer inFile.Close()

    outFile, err := os.Create(filePathOut)
    if err != nil { return err }
    defer outFile.Close()

    iv := make([]byte, IV_SIZE)
    _, err = rand.Read(iv)
    if err != nil { return err }

    aes, err := aes.NewCipher(keyAes)
    if err != nil { return err }

    ctr := cipher.NewCTR(aes, iv)
    hmac := hmac.New(sha256.New, keyHmac)

    buf := make([]byte, BUFFER_SIZE)
    for {
        n, err := inFile.Read(buf)
        if err != nil && err != io.EOF { return err }

        outBuf := make([]byte, n)
        ctr.XORKeyStream(outBuf, buf[:n])
        hmac.Write(outBuf)
        outFile.Write(outBuf)

        if err == io.EOF { break }
    }

    outFile.Write(iv)
    hmac.Write(iv)
    outFile.Write(hmac.Sum(nil))

    return nil
}
```

Comment: I modified [your code to run a real demo](https://play.golang.org/p/JBbOviomums). How does AES-CTR compare to other schemes? How do you handle someone changing the order of blocks? [D.A.R.E](https://github.com/minio/sio)

Comment: CTR is as close as you get to GCM, just without the authentication part. It's a stream cipher, which makes it perfect for this scenario. The only downside is that it falls apart if you reuse a nonce and key for two messages.  It's easy to avoid doing this, however, by just always using a random nonce.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "order of the blocks"?  Do you mean for the first method I outlined?  The second has no concept of blocks.  The first would require some mechanism to account for ordering, yes.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, GCM seems to be [CTR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Counter_(CTR)) with the [new Galois mode of authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois/Counter_Mode). This means plain CTR needs to handle signing and ordering each block in the stream so they aren't removed or re-ordered by a malicious actor.

Comment: CTR is a **stream** cipher.  There are no blocks.  It is literally bit-by-bit.  The reordering and modification checks are handled by the HMAC.  There is no signing occuring here, either.

Comment: _`The reordering and modification checks are handled by the HMAC.`_ This is what I was referring to. Looking at what you posted, it doesn't seem like there is 1) any order information or 2) a new IV chosen for each buffer (I was calling it a block by mistake).

Comment: Another recommendation for CTR + HMAC: http://www.daemonology.net/blog/2009-06-24-encrypt-then-mac.html

Comment: I think we are misunderstanding each other somewhere. The code example I provided is for the second method. This method doesn't need any ordering information and only needs one nonce. This is why I said it was preferred over the first method. The buffering is only required so we can write to the HMAC and the output file at the same time, it has nothing to do with the structure of the encrypted file. Additionally, the example I provided does follow the Encrypt-then-MAC scheme.  I feel like you might be misunderstanding something in the example.

Comment: Sorry, I was reading it wrong. I was assuming that your CTR example was a stream of `encrypt(4096 byte buf) + HMAC` chunks appended one after the other to a file (so I thought they could be reordered). However, it clearly is a single `encrypted(blob) + HMAC.`

Comment: No worries.  Hope this helps.  Like I said, the only downside is the decryption step.  Your stream has to be seekable (or you have to save the entire stream to a file) so that you can do one pass for the HMAC and another for decryption.

Comment: Google drive client (in Go) uses [AES-CTR + AES-512 HMAC](https://github.com/odeke-em/drive/wiki/End-to-End-Encryption) just as you show.

Comment: GoCryptfs uses [GCM with 4kB ordered chunks](https://github.com/rfjakob/gocryptfs/blob/64e5906ffa1f225a51048b3d0ac6b1a09e2ca170/internal/contentenc/content.go#L124)

Comment: @LukeJoshuaPark Is it possible for you to write a sample for decryption and elaborate a bit more about it?

Comment: How would I decrypt the output of the encrypt function?

Answer (score 5):

Using HMAC after encryption is a valid method. However, HMAC can be pretty slow, especially if SHA-2 is used. You could actually do the same with GMAC, the underlying MAC of GCM. It may be tricky to find an implementation but GMAC is over the ciphertext, so you can simply perform it separately if you really want. There are other methods as well such as Poly1305 with AES as used for TLS 1.2 and 1.3.

For GCM (or CCM or EAX or any other authenticated cipher) you need to authenticate the order of the chunks. You could do this by creating a separate file encryption key and then using the nonce input (the 12 byte IV) to indicate the number of the chunk. This will solve the storage of the IV *and* make sure that the chunks are in order. You can generate the file encryption key using a KDF (if you have a unique way to indicate the file) or by wrapping a random key with a master key.